# d3 drag only works when axis ticks are highlighted

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I'm working on a package that merges Angular and D3 (v3) and specifically and trying to incorporate D3's dragging feature into the package. I'm very close to being successful, but when my plots render for the first time, I am unable to drag the elements (in this case rectangles) unless I use my cursor to select the text on the x-axis. After the text is highlighted, the user can drag the rectangles and the feature seems to work perfectly, but I really would like to fix the initial bug.

I've replicated the issue in a [Github.io project found here](https://krfurlong.github.io/ivmlDraggingExample/). I define the dragging behavior from d3 in the library ivml.0.0.0 (included [in the repo](https://github.com/krfurlong/ivmlDraggingExample/blob/master/ivml.0.0.0.js)) in lines 903-966 which I'll include below:

```
    if (Bars.events.dragE) {

        // Note: xs(0) refers to pixel value at 0 on the x-scale. Must be reset for generalizability

        // function returns width (in pixels) of bar. Used to ensure drag doesn't exceed plot area

        function returnw(d, i){
            if (values_function(d, i) <= 0) {
                Bars.elements.barController.offset(position_function(d, i), xs(0) - xs(values_function(d, i)), values_function(d, i));
                return xs(0) - xs(values_function(d, i));
            }
            else {
                Bars.elements.barController.offset(position_function(d, i), xs(values_function(d, i)) - xs(0), values_function(d, i))
                return Math.abs(xs(0)-xs(values_function(d, i)))
            }
        }

        var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
        .on('dragstart', draginit)
        .on('drag', dragmove)
        .on('dragend', dragfin);

        function draginit(d){
            d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
            // replace fill color with variable for user input function
            Bars.events.dragE(d, i, d3.select(this).attr('style', 'fill: yellow; stroke: black; stroke-width: 3px;'))
        }

        function dragmove(d){
            var svgwidth = Bars.elements.chartController.plotObject.attributes.width //margin of plotObject
            var svginterval = svgwidth/(Bars.elements.chartController.plotObject.attributes.xmax-Bars.elements.chartController.plotObject.attributes.xmin) //number of pixels between whole numbers in coordinate plot
            Bars.events.dragE(d, i, 
            d3.select(this)
                .attr("x", function(d, i){
                    if (d3.event.x < 0) {return 0}
                    else if (d3.event.x + returnw(d,i) > svgwidth){ return (svgwidth - returnw(d,i))}
                    else {return xs(Math.floor(d3.event.x/svginterval)) } })); //this function ensures value will be a whole number         

            var valuechange = d3.event.x < 0 ? 0 : (d3.event.x + returnw(d,i) > svgwidth ? svgwidth - returnw(d,i) : d3.event.x);

            console.log("Start value changed to: ", Math.floor(valuechange/svginterval));
        }

        function dragfin(d){
            Bars.events.dragE(d, i, d3.select(this).attr('style', 'stroke: black; stroke-width: 0px;')
            .attr('fill', Bars.attributes.fill))

        }


        rects.attr("cursor", "ew-resize")
        .on('dragstart', function(d, i){
            Bars.events.dragE(d, i, d3.select(this).call(drag))
        })
        .on('drag', function (d, i) {
            window.dragThis = this;
            Bars.events.dragE(d, i, 
                d3.select(this).call(drag)) 
        })
        .on("dragend", function(d, i){
            Bars.events.dragE(d, i, d3.select(this).call(drag))

        })
    }
```

I'm still somewhat new to both Angular and Javascript/D3, so I might be missing something really basic, but any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

I have written a d3v5 of the bar-graph-drag behavior that you want and there is no problem with any selection needed first. I suggest to skip the D3-Angular interface and draw the D3 stuff yourself in D3v5 by calling a function that draws the graph based on the data supplied in an argument.

In the [original bar graph](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304) data the bar value was the `frequency` field of the object.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- based on bar chart https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304 -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
.active {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
.axis--y path {
  display: none;
}
</style>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([0, width]),
    y = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([height, 0]).paddingInner(0.1);

var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var data = [
    {letter: 'A', x: 0, frequency: 1 },
    {letter: 'B', x: 0, frequency: 13 },
    {letter: 'C', x: 0, frequency: 6 },
    {letter: 'D', x: 0, frequency: 2 },
    {letter: 'E', x: 0, frequency: 5 },
    {letter: 'F', x: 0, frequency: 9 }
];

var colorFx = function(d, i){
                  var colors = ['blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'purple', 'orange'];
                  return colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
              };

  x.domain([0, 7 + d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);
  y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));


  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

  g.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("fill", colorFx)
      .attr("x", function(d) { return 0; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.letter); })
      .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.frequency); } )
      .attr("height", y.bandwidth() )
    .call(d3.drag()
      .on("start", dragstarted)
      .on("drag", dragged)
      .on("end", dragended));

var prevDragPosition = { x: 0, y: 0};

function dragstarted(d) {
  prevDragPosition.x = d3.event.x;
  prevDragPosition.y = d3.event.y;
  d3.select(this).classed("active", true);
}

function dragged(d) {
  // how much do we have to move the rect
  var deltaX = x.invert(d3.event.x) - x.invert(prevDragPosition.x);
  var node = d3.select(this);
  var dd = node.attr("x");
  var rectX = d.x + deltaX;
  // limit x position to the domain
  rectX = Math.max(x.domain()[0], rectX);
  rectX = Math.min(x.domain()[1]-d.frequency, rectX);
  d.x = rectX;
  node.attr("x", x(rectX));
  prevDragPosition.x = d3.event.x;
  prevDragPosition.y = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d, i) {
  d3.select(this).classed("active", false);
}

</script>
```

Comment: Normally I would agree with you and just use D3 (and use the latest version), but a main objective for the Angular-D3 interface is to make building interactive visualizations more intuitive and approachable for people who aren't familiar/comfortable with D3. Thanks, though!

Comment: I have had a look at your git repository and it is very much unreadable. What I see about the Angular-D3 stuff is that it is some kind of wrapper for D3 with just a different syntax and it does not make it easier. It only obfuscates the nice D3 API. You need to understand D3 before you can write these wrapper calls.